# Dynamic NSMutableDictionary and add it to NSMutableArray (initWithObjects)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, objective-c, mobile

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* friends_data;

- (void)initFriendsData
  {   

 //*****Here its static values, and the eight NSMutableDictionary are added in a list

   NSMutableDictionary* f1 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
   [f1 setObject:@"Natalie H." forKey:@"name"];
   [f1 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_boy1"] forKey:@"image"];
   [f1 setObject:@"Just now" forKey:@"time"];
   [f1 setObject:@"added you as a friend" forKey:@"event"];

   NSMutableDictionary* f2 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [f2 setObject:@"Dale P." forKey:@"name"];
   [f2 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-med"] forKey:@"image"];
   [f2 setObject:@"19 min. ago" forKey:@"time"];
   [f2 setObject:@"earned" forKey:@"event"];
   [f2 setObject:@"500 points" forKey:@"result"];

   NSMutableDictionary* f3 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [f3 setObject:@"Matt M." forKey:@"name"];
   [f3 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_boy2"] forKey:@"image"];
   [f3 setObject:@"42 min. ago" forKey:@"time"];
   [f3 setObject:@"wants to be friend" forKey:@"event"];
   [f3 setObject:@"add" forKey:@"operation"];

    NSMutableDictionary* f4 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [f4 setObject:@"SarahBeth S." forKey:@"name"];
    [f4 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-profile"] forKey:@"image"];
    [f4 setObject:@"1 hour ago" forKey:@"time"];
    [f4 setObject:@"earned" forKey:@"event"];
    [f4 setObject:@"385 points" forKey:@"result"];

    NSMutableDictionary* f5 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [f5 setObject:@"Jeremy F." forKey:@"name"];
    [f5 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-profile"] forKey:@"image"];
    [f5 setObject:@"1 hour ago" forKey:@"time"];
    [f5 setObject:@"wants to be friends" forKey:@"event"];
    [f5 setObject:@"add" forKey:@"operation"];

    NSMutableDictionary* f6 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [f6 setObject:@"Minuyu C." forKey:@"name"];
    [f6 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_boy2"] forKey:@"image"];
    [f6 setObject:@"2 hour ago" forKey:@"time"];
    [f6 setObject:@"has reached" forKey:@"event"];
    [f6 setObject:@"level 10" forKey:@"result"];

     NSMutableDictionary* f7 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     [f7 setObject:@"Jeremy F." forKey:@"name"];
     [f7 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-profile"] forKey:@"image"];
     [f7 setObject:@"2 hour ago" forKey:@"time"];
     [f7 setObject:@"wants to be friends" forKey:@"event"];
     [f7 setObject:@"add" forKey:@"operation"];

     NSMutableDictionary* f8 = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     [f8 setObject:@"SarahBeth S." forKey:@"name"];
     [f8 setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-profile"] forKey:@"image"];
     [f8 setObject:@"5 hour ago" forKey:@"time"];
     [f8 setObject:@"earned" forKey:@"event"];
     [f8 setObject:@"185 points" forKey:@"result"];


     friends_data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8, nil];


        ………………………………………………………………………….………………………………………………………………………….………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….………………………………………………………………………….………………………………………………………………………….………………………………………………………………………….………………………………………………………………………….

    ****** Why this code passing just one value in the List? How to make it dynamic?

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“URL”]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:kNilOptions
                                  error:&error];
    NSArray *alertArray = [json objectForKey:@"data"];

    for (NSDictionary *alert in alertArray ){
    // NSString* name  = [alert  objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSMutableDictionary* theJsonData = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [theJsonData setObject:[alert objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [theJsonData setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-profile"] forKey:@"image"];
    [theJsonData setObject:@"5 hour ago" forKey:@"time"];
    [theJsonData setObject:@"earned" forKey:@"event"];
    [theJsonData setObject:@"185 points" forKey:@"result"];

    friends_data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:theJsonData, nil];
            }                
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand. "Why this code passing just one value in the List?": passing what to where? "How to make it dynamic?": what?  Also consider using modern Objective-C literals for both dictionaries and arrays; it will be worth it.

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to initialize you array outside the loop and dynamically add the obects inside the loop.

```
        friends_data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *alert in alertArray ){
           // NSString* name  = [alert  objectForKey:@"name"];

            NSMutableDictionary* theJsonData = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [theJsonData setObject:[alert objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [theJsonData setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-profile"] forKey:@"image"];
            [theJsonData setObject:@"5 hour ago" forKey:@"time"];
            [theJsonData setObject:@"earned" forKey:@"event"];
            [theJsonData setObject:@"185 points" forKey:@"result"];
            [friends_data addObject:theJsonData];
       }
```

Comment: How about if[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatars-med"] forKey:@"image"] is downloaded from the web?

Comment: Can you be more precise in your question?